# How to get multiple cams connected

Tags: vb.net, video, webcam, video-capture, vfw

I am trying to connect multiple webcams at the same time but it produces the Video source dialog to select the webcam. IS there any way to bypass it? Can I pass the webcamm info explicitly?

Here is the code that is producing the problem

```
Dim infoReturn As VariantType
infoReturn = SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, iDevice, 0)
If SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, iDevice, 0) Then
  'Set the preview scale
  Call SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_SCALE, True, 0)
```

`WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT` is the message that shows the dialog.

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You send `WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT` twice, you don't need to. This is ancient Video for Windows API and you don't have flexibility to override default behavior, nor you have support for full range of video capture sources with it.

Perhaps you should rather look into switching to newer APIs (DriectShow/Media Foundation).